# RabbitMQ topology created by MassTransit

Tags: masstransit

I'am trying to understand the [topology of queues](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/configuration/transports/rabbitmq.html?highlight=topology#routing-topology) and exchanges MT creates in RabbitMQ.

I cannot get these two statements:

> - we generate an exchange for each queue so that we can do direct sends
>     to the queue. it is bound as a fanout exchange (is it about sending vs publishing?)
> - control queues are exclusive and auto-delete - they go away when you
>     go away and are not shared.

What for does MT need to send direct messages? Does this relate to `control queues` used by MT internally?

<strike>There is also no mentioning about `dead letter queue`, does that imply MT does not support one out of the box?</strike>
Oops, looked in a wrong place. It's [here](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/usage/exceptions.html?highlight=error#handling-exceptions).

Comment: I don't think we generate control queues any more, at least not normally. But control queues have been used as a side channel to exchange data that wouldn't be delayed because of the consumption rate on the data (primary) queue.

Comment: This page needs updated for sure.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson As we just started looking at MT, I'am going to bother you with more questions =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Michael Aldworth has described this in details in his excellent [MassTransit Send vs. Publish](https://www.maldworth.com/2015/10/27/masstransit-send-vs-publish/) blog post.

Essentially, for each MT endpoint, you get a exchange-queue pair, which is named after the `queueName` parameter value in the endpoint configuration. Topics, at the other hand, are RabbitMQ exchanges named after the message contract full type name.

**Publish**

You send a message to the topic, meaning to the message type exchange. MassTransit creates binding between the message type exchange and queue-name exchange on start up. In such way subscriptions work on the RabbitMQ levels. Publisher never knows who will be receiving the published message, if anyone at all.

[image: Publishing]

**Send**

When sending, however, you need to specify the receiver address. By doing this you instruct MassTransit to deliver the message directly to the queue-name exchange. There is no binding between message-type exchange and queue-name exchange involved here. Therefore, the message will be delivered even if there is no consumer for this type of message at the target service. In such case the message will be moved to the deadletter queue (queue-name_Skipped).

[image]

Comment: @PavelVoronin I expected that but I thought it would be nice to have it here as well :) Will update the docs too...